# Performance with multiple instances of rsync across different direct-attached storage devices?

Tags: command-line, external-hard-drive, rsync, cpu-usage, data-transfer

Would running multiple instances of rsync with all the sources and destinations on different direct-attached storage devices cause any performance hits, or would the speed limits for each individual rsync transfer be due *only* to the read/write speeds of the direct-attached storage devices within the individual rsync commands themselves?

For instance, suppose I want to transfer:

> Camera Card 1 to Direct-Attached Hard Drive 1

and

> Camera Card 2 to Direct-Attached Hard Drive 2

If I run these rsync commands simultaneously, will the two rsync instances slow each other down, or will the speed limit for each individual instance *still* just be whatever the slowest device read/write speed is *within* each rsync instance?

Assume that the device interfaces are not bottlenecks.

Comment: You'd have to specify what parameters you are using. Remember, there is CPU also involved since you may be performing rolling comparison of bits, deleting, copying, mirroring, etc.

Comment: @Sun I'd just be doing `-avv [SRC] [DEST]`.

Comment: [Compression will use CPU](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188737/does-compression-option-z-with-rsync-speed-up-backup), but probably a waste of CPU cycles since most images and video is already highly compressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an opportunity to run an experiment with this, so I figured I'd post an answer for anyone curious.

Any performance hit from the CPU is is imperceptible, if it even exists. As long as different devices aren't competing for the read or write speeds from other devices, there is no penalty to the rate of data transfer.

To illustrate, `DAS A` can transfer to `DAS B` at the same time `DAS C` transfers to `DAS D`, and the bottleneck for `A` to `B` is either `A`'s read speed or `B`'s write speed, unaffected by the other `rsync` instance transferring from `C` to `D`. Similarly, the `rsync` transfer from `C` to `D` is unaffected by the `rsync` instance transferring from `A` to `B`.